# save data from two table input to one excel write in pentaho

Tags: excel, pentaho

In pentaho I want to recover two data from two different tables and enter them in a row of an excel.

The transformation: 
[image: One Get System Info and one Table input to one Microsoft Excel Writer]

Get System Info:
[image: Name: FECHA; Type: systemdate(variable)]

Table input:
[image: Select count(*) as ORDENES from orden;]

MicrosoftExcel Write (File & Sheet):
[image]

MicrosoftExcel Write (Content):
[image: Fields FECHA -> FECHA; ORDENES->ORDENES]

The error:
[image: Couldn't find field [ORDENES] in row!]

Comment: I see you are using the **variable** system time. This may be what you need. Warn however that you can also use the **fixed** system time, that is the time at which the transformation started to run. This may be useful if, for example, you want to retrieve in one operation all the data loaded in a certain run.

Answer (score 2):

To merge two (or more) in coming steams in one step (your Excel Writer), the metadata (column name and type) must be the same. Hence the error.

What you probably want to do is to add the time as an extra column on each row of the *orden*. You usually do this with the `Join rows` (which is not a Cartesian product despite its misleading name).

In the case of the `Get System Info` the answer is simpler as this step adds the info on new columns. Just use it sequentially !
  [image]

Comment: Perfect! I needed the step 'Join rows' since I need to load data from more than two table input. Thank you very much AlainD! :)

Comment: Then. Have a look to the `Stream Lookup` step. The main difference from a join from a user point of view is that a Lookup will look for exactly one (or none) row in a table rather than a set of matching rows. From a system point of view there an ocean which makes the lookup more stable, faster and easier to maintain. Furthermore you can lookup in transformed the data rather that in the raw extract form the database.